# removing vertex groups that got a dot on its name

Tags: python, scripting

I need to find a way to remove vertex groups that got a dot on their names, I tried with this code but it didnt work (well, the find part works, but it is not removing the vertex group):

```
for vertexname in bpy.context.object.vertex_groups:
if vertexname.name.find("\."):
    vertexname.remove(vertexname.index)
```

***ValueError: VertexGroup.remove(): error with argument 1, "index" -  sequence expected at dimension 1, not 'int'***

I'm not very experienced with python either, i could make that code because of my knowledge with lua, not really sure what does a sequence is in python (i was expecting it to be a table with numbers, something like [0, 1, 5, etc] but even with "vertexname.remove([0])" nothing is being removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Each item `vg` when iterating over `object.vertex_groups` is an instance of
  a `bpy.types.VertexGroup` object.  (just as each of `bpy.data.objects` is an instance of an `bpy.types.Object` object)
- Remove `vg` from the objects vertex group collection with
  `ob.vertex_groups.remove(vg)`  A vertex group object also has a remove method, which takes a sequence of vertex indices as an argument. Eg `vg.remove([0, 1])`. *This prob led to the confusion re error message*
- No need to escape out the period.

  ```
  >>> str("\.") 
  '\\.'
  ```
- If a substring is not in string then `find(...)` returns -1

Script:

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
vgs = [vg for vg in ob.vertex_groups
       if vg.name.find(".") != -1]

while(vgs):
    ob.vertex_groups.remove(vgs.pop())
```

To make the scripts portable (copy paste jobs) I like to break down variables.  Eg one edit to test with `ob = context.scene.objects.get("Cube")` no matter what the context object.

I favour the "while pop" method, a `for vg in vgs: ob.vertex_groups.remove(vg)` statement can also be used.  The rationale being once an object is removed in blender, trying to re-reference it can have dire consequences... (well sometimes crash blender)

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer, your code also works awesome! thanks for the help